# Change the value of an input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome-extension, reactjs

I am making a Google Chrome extension that interacts with facebook.
On a facebook page I need to change the value of an input field and then submit it. Which works, but when I press the input field again or click on the Next button the value of the input changes back to what it was before I made the change.

I know that Facebook uses ReactJS. But I don't know where it is used for or if this is what is causing my problem.
If ReactJS is causing the issue how do i fix it?
How can I use jQuery to change ReactJS values?

The input is at https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/creation/creation/. The input of which im trying to change the value is at 'Send people to your website'.

Comment: I see, you're new to stack overflow.. We need your code to analyze what you're mistakes are, so please paste your code and a Fiddle (jsdiddle.net) :)

Comment: Hi @BennetG. I don't really know how i can create a jsfiddle for this problem but i did add the location of the input at the bottom of my question. I hope that this will be enough.

Comment: For the link you need to have a Facebook-Account.. I don't have one :/ That's why im out